# Downcasting of arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I am not sure how downcasting of arrays works.
Example this works:

```
String[] sArray = {"a", "b"};  
Object[] o = sArray;  
f((String[]) o);  

static void f(String[] s){  
  System.out.println("Ok");   
}
```

But for the following:
`new F(cert, (X509Certificate[]) ks.getCertificateChain("ALIAS"), key));`
where `F` is

```
public F(X509Certificate certificate, X509Certificate[] certificateChain, PrivateKey privateKey) {      
}
```

I get `ClassCastException`

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.security.cert.Certificate;
>   incompatible with [Ljava.security.cert.X509Certificate;

Why?

Comment: Its worth remembering that you cast references to objects.  When you do this the object referenced is not changed or copied.  This means the reference must always be valid for the object it references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays in Java are objects, and as such, have a class. They aren't simply identityless containers. When you say:

```
String[] sArray = {"a", "b"};
```

You are creating an object of class `String[]`, and putting two strings in it. There is an alternative way of writing it which makes that clearer:

```
String[] sArray = new String[] {"a", "b"};
```

You can cast references to arrays in much the same way as you can cast references to any other objects; you can always make a widening conversion (eg assigning an expression of type `String[]` to a variable of type `Object[]`), and you can make a narrowing conversion using an explicit cast (eg assigning an expression of type `Object[]` to a variable of type `String[]`). As with other objects, when you do an explicit case, the actual class of the object is checked at runtime, and if it doesn't fit the desired type, a `ClassCastException` is thrown. As with other objects, the actual *class of the object* does not change when you cast. Only the *type of the variable* does.

In your case, it looks like `ks.getCertificateChain("ALIAS")` returns a `Certificate[]`. It's possible that the elements in it are instances of `X509Certificate`, but the array itself is still a `Certificate[]`. When you try to cast it to `X509Certificate[]`, that fails.

If you need a `X509Certificate[]`, then what you will have to do is copy the contents of the array into a new array which is a `X509Certificate[]`. You can do that as tbk suggests, or you can call [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28U%5B%5D,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%29), looking something like:

```
Certificate[] Certificates = ks.getCertificateChain("ALIAS");
X509Certificate[] x509Certificates = Arrays.copyOf(certificates, certificates.length, X509Certificate[].class);
```

Comment: `Arrays.copyOf()` is just another wrapper around `System.arraycopy()`, so the output is semantically the same. In the end, it all relates down to the fact that the cast down can not be performed on an array, because the runtime does not (can not?) check if ALL objects inside the array are of the desired subtype (in this case `X509Certificate`). Seems like we are stuck with the userspace checking of types, no matter where the actually type checking takes place (inside the SDK as part of `Arrays.copyOf()` or `System.arraycopy()` OR in your own code).

Comment: @tbk: It's true that `copyOf` is (probably) just a wrapper round `arraycopy` - its only advantage is that it's a single method call.

Comment: @TomAnderson:You are right.There are entries of `X509Certificate` inside the `Certificate[]` but nevertheless (they can not be cast to `X509Certificate[]`?

Comment: @Jim: Correct, the array cannot be downcast, because the array *is not* a `X509Certificate[]`, it's a `Certificate[]`. The fact that it only contains `X509Certificate`s is actually irrelevant here. If i fill an empty lemonade bottle with champagne, does it become a champagne bottle?

Answer (score 2):

You can not cast down an array in java, but you can work around it by doing the following:

```
Certificate[] certs = ...;
X509Certificate[] x509certs = new X509Certificate[certs.length];
for(int i = 0; i < certs.length; i++) {
  x509certs[i] = (X509Certificate)certs[i];
}
```

Edit: An alternative to this is shown [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500044/downcasting-an-array-in-java-remove-the-unchecked-warning-game). However, it involves `System.arraycopy()` which will likely perform the same when it comes to runtime.

Comment: Because the compiler is able to resolve that `o` is actually referencing `String[] sArray`.

Comment: So it depends on the context?

Comment: In the first example you created a `String[]`, assigned it to an `Object[]` variable and then cast this back to `String[]`. If you had created an `Object[]` to start with you would not have been able to cast it to `String[]` even if all the items inside it were strings, it's the runtime type of the array itself that matters.